# Grails: how to apply constraint on column to be shown in list

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I am new to grail, please give me idea how to apply constraint on column to be shown in list after writing scaffolding true in the controller i.e. i have columns in domain- name,email,password,phone but i want to show only name, email and phone in the grid when the list will be displayed, is there any way to do this through domain? please give me a solution for this thanks.

Comment: Only on list or on all scaffolding views of said domain class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the templates (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html)

```
grails install-templates
```

Templates give you access to overwrite the default templating that Grails uses in controllers, views, etc.  If you look at src/templates/scaffolding/list.gsp you can see that they are already excluding some properties ('id' and 'version).  I added a static list to my domain class:

```
static excludedFromListViewProperties = ["password"]
```

In the list.gsp I replaced:

```
<%  excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'id' << 'version'                           
allowedNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated'
```

with:

```
<%  excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'id' << 'version'
excludedProps.addAll(domainClass.getClazz().excludedFromListViewProperties ?: [])
allowedNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated'
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

scaffolding make things behind the scene. You can generate all views and controllers of specific domain class via:

```
grails generate-all packageName.DomainClass
```

After command is executed, you can simply change generated controllers and views as you wish.

Comment: yes i know that but i don't have to do this. is there any way to apply some constraints on the columns that will show in list?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Dynamic Scaffolding](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/single.html#16.Scaffolding) which states

> Also, the standard scaffold views expect model variables of the form InstanceList for collections and Instance for single instances. It's tempting to use properties like 'books' and 'book', but those won't work.

So, maybe you can override your scaffolding actions by returning instances with only the fields you want. But you may need an intermediary data type I think. This is a way to explore

Answer (score 0):

A slightly improved version of Jarred's answer that checks the existence of the excludedFromListViewProperties property:

```
domainClass.getClazz().metaClass.properties.findAll{
   if (it.name == "excludedFromListViewProperties"){
        excludedProps.addAll(domainClass.getClazz().excludedFromListViewProperties ?: [])
    }
}
```